# Error in passing Struct as argument to a function by value in gcc ver 4.6.3

Tags: c, linux, gcc

I am a newbie to C Programming and I am learning to pass a struct as a parameter to a function (as part of my course) by value. I am using gcc ver 4.6.3 on Ubuntu Linux 12.04LTS
The following is the source code which seems logically and syntactically correct (to me) but I get errors when compiling it:

```
#include<stdio.h>

struct sal {
    char name[30];
    int no_of_days_worked;
    int daily_wage;
};
typedef struct sal Sal;

void main()
{
    Sal salary;
    int amount_payable;
    salary=get_data(salary);           //Passing struct as function arguments
    printf("\nThe name of the Employee is %s",salary.name);
    printf("\nNumber of days worked is %d",salary.no_of_days_worked);
    printf("\nThe daily wage of the employees is %d",salary.daily_wage);
    amount_payable=wages(salary);
    printf("\nThe amount payable to %s is %d",salary.name,amount_payable);
}

Sal get_data(Sal income)
{
    printf("\nEnter the name of the Employee: \n");
    scanf("%s",&income.name);
    printf("\nEnter the number of days worked:\n");
    scanf("%d",&income.no_of_days_worked);
    printf("\nEnter the employee daily wages:\n");
    scanf("%d",&income.daily_wage);
    return(income);                                //Return back a struct data type
}

int wages(Sal x)
{
    int total_salary;
    total_salary=x.no_of_days_worked*x.daily_wage;
    return(total_salary);
}
```

On compiling the code I get the following errors:

```
struct_to_function.c: In function ‘main’:
struct_to_function.c:15:7: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘Sal’ from type ‘int’
struct_to_function.c: At top level:
struct_to_function.c:22:5: error: conflicting types for ‘get_data’
struct_to_function.c:15:8: note: previous implicit declaration of ‘get_data’ was here
struct_to_function.c: In function ‘get_data’:
struct_to_function.c:25:1: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char (*)[30]’ [-Wformat]
```

I think it has some thing to do with the implementation or execution plan of the gcc compiler whether the compiler is using a stack or registers. Again these are just my amateurish assumptions.

Comment: Apart from the remarks by others, "scanf("%s",&income.name);" should better be "scanf("%s",income.name);" since the array decays into a pointer to its first element, i.e. a char*, all on its own. Getting the address of the array is strictly spoken a type error, although the result should afaict have the same numerical value, i.e. the scanf should work. Just don't increment the pointer ;-).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the C compiler encounters the call to `get_data` from `main`, it has no idea what the return type is (since it has seen neither a function declaration nor a function definition), so it assumes `int`.  This gives you the first warning, because `salary` is incompatible with `int` in the assignment.  The compiler keeps going, now thinking that `get_data` returns `int`, and then it complains when it encounters the actual definition of `get_data`.

You should either add a function prototype before `main`, or make sure that functions are always defined before being called (by rearranging their order in the source code).

The final warning is because the `scanf` with a `%s` specifier is expecting a `char*`, but you gave it something of type `char (*)[30]`.  Leave off the `&` when passing an array.

Just add the following before main:

```
Sal get_data(Sal income);
int wages(Sal x);
```

Comment: Actually, the compiler assumes that the **return value** of get_data() is int. (Which is assigned to a Salary which of course doesn't work.)

Comment: I have placed the function prototype declarations before main() and now the program compiles and runs perfectly. I was so stupid not to think about how C executes the instructions/code in linear fashion. I was just running the program for learning/demonstration; otherwise it is not a good practice to pass structures by value as pointed out by the learned forum members here. Thanks Everyone esp Peter Schneider for eloquently explaining the reason for this error.

Answer (score -1):

<strike>You have to pass a pointer to the structure.  When you try to pass the structure itself, the C compiler tries to make a copy of it, but it doesn't know how to do that (you would need to use C++ to be able to define that) so it's an error.</strike>

You didn't declare the functions before you used them, so the compiler created it's own default definition for you.  You have to declare a function before you reference it.

Also, it's bad practice to pass the structure by value and then modify it and pass it back.  Better to just pass the pointer to the object you want to modify.

So:

```
int wages( Sal x );
void get_data( Sal* income );
void main()
{
    Sal salary;
    int amount_payable;
    get_data( &salary );           //Passing struct as function arguments
    // print stuff
    amount_payable = wages( salary );
    // print stuff
}
void get_data( Sal* income )
{
    printf( "\nEnter the name of the Employee: \n" );
    scanf( "%s", income->name );
    printf( "\nEnter the number of days worked:\n" );
    scanf( "%d", &(income->no_of_days_worked) );
    printf( "\nEnter the employee daily wages:\n" );
    scanf( "%d", &(income->daily_wage) );
}
int wages( Sal x )
{
    int total_salary;
    total_salary = x.no_of_days_worked * x.daily_wage;
    return total_salary;
}
```

Comment: Wrong.  The C compiler can pass structures by value.  You just need to give it the prototypes before you call them.

Comment: @pat You can't return the structure back and assign it to a structure that's already allocated though.  And it's not good practice to read data into a structure passed in that way.

Comment: Also not true.  You can return a struct by value, and overwrite one that is allocated at the call site.

Comment: It's not advisable to pass an *uninitialized* struct to `get_data` by value though, and pretty useless since the input value is not being used.

Comment: @pat Hmmm, I remember it didn't use to work, back in the early 90's.  It's still an issue of dealing with a copy, which is hidden by using a structure, so I'd still say it's bad practice to do it as you can easily get tripped up by that.

Comment: @JonS Yes, K&R C could do (citing from memory) "exactly two things with a struct: taking its address and accessing a member." (From the K&R book.) This changed -- for the last 20 years or so you can pass them as params (as value!) and assign them to each other.